# Device screen lock-unlock state event in android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I m working on an app where i have to get the event or device state when device screen is on but not locked screen is not unlocked. Does any body has any idea about it. Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please specify more.

Answer (score 2):

You have three broadcasts available Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON and Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.
First is pretty obvious.
The other two are distinct in the way the user wakes the screen. If it is just a wake it is ACTION_SCREEN_ON, if it is followed by unlocking the screen Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT is launched too.

Make a broadcast receiver with a following intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Alternatively to get current state you can use 
[Display.getState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getState())
and 
[PowerManager.isInteractive()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive())

Comment: Thanks i will try this and will let u know if i still have some questions.

Comment: Please note that SCREEN_OFF and SCREEN_ON would NOT be delivered if registered in Manifest. You should register them in service or activity.